# iPhone audio in background and the home button

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I have an app with audio that opens a URL in Safari. The audio keeps playing while the app goes into the background and Safari becomes active.

Problem is, when the Home button is pressed and the app goes into the background, I'd like the audio to stop. Is it possible?

- `AVAudioSession` category is `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`
- Audio is `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodPlayer]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` instead of `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` to read more check out apple docs on session [categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html)